# Traffic Control - Searching clsact filters by parent ID

Tags: linux-kernel, traffic-filtering

According to [net, sched: add clsact qdisc](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/netdev/net.git/commit/?id=1f211a1b929) you add filter on `ingress` and `egress` after adding `clsact`,e.g.

```
 ➜  tc qdisc add dev foo clsact
 ➜  tc qdisc show dev foo
 ➜  tc filter add dev foo ingress bpf da obj bar.o sec ingress
 ➜  tc filter add dev foo egress  bpf da obj bar.o sec egress
 ➜  tc filter show dev foo ingress
 filter protocol all pref 49152 bpf
 filter protocol all pref 49152 bpf handle 0x1 bar.o:[ingress] direct-action
 ➜  tc filter show dev foo egress
 filter protocol all pref 49152 bpf
 filter protocol all pref 49152 bpf handle 0x1 bar.o:[egress] direct-action
```

But wait, what is that `egress` in the last `tc` command call? Let's examine it as a qdisc

```
tc qdisc show dev foo egress
```

res: *What is "egress"? Try "tc qdisc help"*

So what is it, if it's not a qdisc identifiable by name?

I've used strace to get to know what `netlink` message is sent into the kernel:

```bash
strace  -o strace.out  tc filter show dev foo egress && cat strace.out | grep sendmsg
```

What I've got:

```
sendmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_NETLINK, nl_pid=0, nl_groups=00000000}, 
msg_namelen=12, msg_iov=[{iov_base=[{nlmsg_len=36, nlmsg_type=RTM_GETTFILTER, 
nlmsg_flags=NLM_F_REQUEST|NLM_F_DUMP, nlmsg_seq=1682363678, nlmsg_pid=0}, 
{tcm_family=AF_UNSPEC, tcm_ifindex=if_nametoindex("foo"), tcm_handle=0, tcm_parent=4294967283, 
tcm_info=0}], iov_len=36}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, 0) = 36
```

where `tcm_parent=4294967283=0xfffffff3`

So, `egress` is idetified by `ffff:fff3`

and it's true:

```
tc filter show dev foo parent ffff:fff3
```

shows the filter.

But  who owns that `ffff:fff3` while if I try to check that out I get amazing results:

```
➜  tc qdisc show dev foo handle ffff:fff0
qdisc clsact ffff: parent ffff:fff1 
➜ tc qdisc show dev foo handle ffff:fff3
qdisc clsact ffff: parent ffff:fff1 
➜ tc qdisc show dev foo handle ffff:fff35
qdisc clsact ffff: parent ffff:fff1
```

Can anyone explain it to me what is going on here?